# Program stopped working after system update

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, cuda, gpu

I've been using the a program called [gpuNUFFT](https://github.com/andyschwarzl/gpuNUFFT) for a long time now and after updating my system to Ubuntu 20.04 it stopped working and I'm getting a missing file error:

```
libcufft.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to look it up and this appears to be a [library that CUDA uses to perform FFTs](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html) which makes sense why it's looking for it but not why it's missing.

I have `CUDA Version 11.4` and `nvcc V10.1.243` so I'm not sure why this one particular library is missing.

I tried to find the folder which contains these library file by doing echo `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but that just returned an empty line.

Any idea how I can debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library version it is looking for is only available with CUDA 10.4 so even though you have CUDA 11 installed you won't find `libcufft.so.7.5` in your `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` directory. Most likely you will find `libcufft.so.10` or higher.

The reason this happened after your update is because CUDA 10.4 is only available up to Ubuntu 18.04 and not 20.04 so you either need to downgrade you OS or rebuild the program so that it will use the more recent library version.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out for me.